# Error code 1146 de MySQL: Error Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

¿Cómo solucionar error `code 1146 de MySQL`?:

> Error Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También, si es posible, me gustaría saber en qué consiste el error y por qué pasa?

Answer (score 1):

Según [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967527/table-performance-schema-session-variables-doesnt-exist) respuesta del foro angloparlante, puede ser que la tabla esté corrompida. Trata de actualizar tu versión de servidor de `mysql`.

Comment: creo que le deberías indicar una respuesta en concreto, para que tu aporte sea mas específico y le sea útil al resto de la comunidad

Comment: Claramente no puedo indicar una respuesta en concreto cuando no hay demasiados detalles. A lo más podría indicar un "Podrías intentar con esto y si no te funciona, con lo otro" y, al menos a mi parecer, sería plagio de buenas respuestas en esa pregunta.

Comment: ummm si citas al autor de la respuesta original para darle créditos, a parte de que es válido no estas haciendo plagio de nada

Comment: Tengo una mejor idea, recortaré la respuesta para hacerla concreta y aplicaré lo que dices. Gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 1):

1. Primero actualizá el servidor MySQL para resolver el problema. Ingresa a la carpeta donde se encuentra instalado MySQL "C:\Program Files\MySQL...\bin". Podés utilizar el siguiente comando: (Recuerda abrir CMD desde este directorio y entonces coloca el siguiente comando)

> ```
> mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force
> ```

2. Luego reinicia el servicio mysql

> ```
> Abre el administrador de tareas -> vea a servicios -> 
>   click derecho en los servicios de MySQL y MySQL Router -> Reinicialos
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me da error al acceder a cualquier tabla con jdbc y javaee 1.8 si el nombre de la tabla en mysqlworkbench está en minusculas (ej. test.persona). Me dice que la tabla no existe. Si cambio el nombre en mysqlworkbench al mismo nombre en mayusculas (test.PERSONA) si accedo OK con persistencia JPA.
No tiene sentido. No entiendo porqué tiene que ser el nombre de la tabla en mayusculas.....